# how to improve update performance in SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-update

I want to speed up my update in SQL server 2005.

*1.I have clustered the indexes used and dropped  unused ones.*

*2.I have used join instead of sub query.*

Any other suggestion to improve the performance?

Comment: What is the reason for the slowness? Is your data huge? Are your CPU / disks / network the bottleneck ? Can you maybe elaborate on your scenario? This just seems too generic to be able to even comment on it

Comment: yes there is huge amount of data to be updated. but i don't think there's any kind of bottleneck